# How to get sum / Qty of same records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables `Company` and `CompanyLike`

**CompanyLike**

1. Id
2. RatingStar
3. Count
4. Companyid

Company and CompanyLike have `1 to Many` relation . One company can have many likes

Company Like Table Will Look Like this

```
+----------------------------+
| ID  RatingStar   Companyid |
+----------------------------+
| 1      5           5636    |
| 2      5           5636    |
| 3      1           101     |
| 4      2            959    |
+----------------------------+
```

Now i want to get count of rating star that how many times RatingStar is `5` , and how many time its `2` against every Companyid

My current working is

```
 SELECT RatingStar AS RatingStar,com.id AS Companyid , c.Id AS Id ,
        com.Name AS CompanyName, Count(RatingStar) AS ratingCount
   FROM CompanyReviewLike AS c
   INNER JOIN Company AS com ON com.id = c.Companyid
   GROUP BY RatingStar ,com.Name , com.id ,c.Id
```

Comment: "My current working is" - and why is it not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to remove `c.id` from your query:

```
select RatingStar as RatingStar,com.id as Companyid  ,com.Name as  
         CompanyName ,  

 Count(RatingStar) as Count,MIN(c.ID) as Id
     from CompanyReviewLike as c
   inner join Company as com on com.id = c.Companyid
 Group By 
 RatingStar ,com.Name , com.id
```

Since every row has a different `c.id`, if you include it in the grouping then every group only contains one row. If you wanted to include *one* `id` value in the result, then pick a suitable aggregate (`MIN` or `MAX` spring to mind) to select one from the group.

---

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e019/1). Result:

```
RATINGSTAR  COMPANYID   COMPANYNAME COUNT
1           101         CompanyB    1
2           959         CompanyC    1
5           5636        CompanyA    2
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh ,i don't know i missed that . Thanks budy :-)

Comment: what if i dont't want to remove `c.Id`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver  i mean to say that i also want `CompanyLike.Id` in my result in that case how to solve this ?

Comment: @Smartboy - In what *way* do you want the ID, given that there are *multiple* rows from that table contributing to the results? I gave one possibility already in my answer - pick the `MIN` or `MAX` value

Comment: i Don't know how to use that , Actually i am creating a `SQLView` of this command and mapping that View in asp.netmvc3 that's why i need to include id as well .

Comment: Is there any way that i get correct result as i want and i also include `C.ID` ?

Comment: @Smartboy - as I've said twice now - there are *multiple* `C.ID` values. Which one do you want us to use?

Comment: I think i am confused , Please put possible solution and use any one you want .

Answer (score 1):

Please check this if you are only concern for rating-star 5 and 2 counts

```
SELECT COM.Name AS CompanyName, C.RatingStar AS RatingStar, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
FROM CompanyLike AS C
INNER JOIN Company AS COM ON COM.id = C.Companyid
GROUP BY C.RatingStar ,COM.Name 
HAVING C.RatingStar IN (5,2)
```

Check this latest one

```
SELECT C.id,COM.Name AS CompanyName, C.RatingStar AS RatingStar, COM.RatingCount AS RatingCount
    FROM CompanyLike C
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT COM.Name AS CompanyName,C.CompanyId, C.RatingStar AS RatingStar, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
                FROM CompanyLike AS C
                INNER JOIN Company AS COM ON COM.id = C.Companyid
                GROUP BY C.RatingStar ,COM.Name ,C.CompanyId
                HAVING C.RatingStar IN (5,2)) COM
    ON C.RatingStar = Com.RatingStar AND C.CompanyId = COM.id
```

Comment: , i also want to include `C.Id` in group By statement by when i do this , it doesn't give me correct results , as Damien told me to use `Min , Max` but i don't know how to use that  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot data. Le'ts supose your tables are:

```
create table compa ( id int, name varchar(10) );
create table likes (idComp int, rating int);
create table rates ( id int);
```

Then your query is:

```
select * 
from (
    select r.id as rate, 
         c.id as comp,
         l.idComp as n
  from compa c
  cross join rates r
  left join likes l
     on l.rating = r.id
        and c.id = l.idComp
) as src
PIVOT
(
count( n )
FOR rate IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] )
) as pvt ;
```

And [results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bf22/8/0):

```
| COMP | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
----------------------------
|    1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|    2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

.

**Explanation**

Select inner query join results between tables to get rates raw data. Pivot clause counts data and move row data to columns to get only a column by company.

Notice rates cross join to get all rates from a company, also left join to get no rates companies.

Enjoy.

Comment: Why we create table `rates` ?

Comment: I like it. But not needed, you can simplify query as: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bf22/13/0

Comment: now it shows me record of all companies but i only want to see in which there is some value , i mean that i only want to see those companies which have any entry in CompanyLike table , if company has 0 entries then it should be skipped .

Comment: then change left join by inner join.

Comment: is this possible without `PIVOT` ? If yes then can you please show me how ?

Comment: You can do it with case statements. Bye.